# Is it possible for average students to get admitted in good colleges for MS?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, united-states, degree, gre

So, if I get a 320 plus GRE score and have a CGPA of 7.0 with no research paper but a lot of social and extracurricular activities, is it possible for me to get admitted to a good college in USA? I have studied computer science and I am interested in getting a MSc degree in Artificial intelligence or Data Science. If yes, how much exceptional my SoP and LoRs should be, since I am an average student and I don’t think I would be getting exceptional LoRs. More importantly, is it possible for me to get admitted in top colleges like Georgia tech (not CMU or UCLA since they are too top notch and I don’t think they would accept me)?

Comment: I am sorry i am new to the place , I will try to edit it as much as i can though i am not good with grammers.

Comment: Learning good English is necessary for writing a good SOP and for being able to study in the USA. You should definitely work on that, before applying.

Comment: @jakebeal well actually it is for MS and what i have heard the admission criteria for phd's are quite strict as compared to MS.

Comment: @Alexandros I understand, am already working on it I can speak good english and i have a good verbal approach but, I have been weak with grammers and punctuations , Since my childhood.

Comment: @AtharvaPandey Much of the advice regarding Ph.D. admissions also applies to research Masters admissions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, I believe that it is possible for average students to get into Masters programs in the US. From my experience, your chances are high if you do well in the GRE Math section and can pay the full tuition. Research experience is only relevant if you intend to enter a PhD program. Focus on your GREs and your personal statement. That way, you'll stand a good chance.

Comment: ok I can pay for full tutions and i am good with quants thankyou ... i guess now my preparations would be worth it.